# Saving App data?

Tags: java, android

In my app it saves data eg when something is clicked on it counts how many times it's been click however when you uninstall the app it removes the data!

I want to get around this problem by maybe making a settings menu where the user can save their current counts into a file that can be saved to the phone and then loaded if they were to reset their phone from scratch?

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or maybe you could store your data on the "cloud" from Google. Every time the user changes a value, you can call the "Backup Agent" to store everything you need on Google servers. So, if the users uninstalls the application and install it again, your "Backup Agents" will be called again with the data stored at the cloud and restore the values you want. For this to be true, your app must be the same and signed with the same key. Different keys (for example release and debug keys) are different applications when using this service.

More info about the Backup service at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html and examples of code at http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/backupapi.html

You just need to modify your AndroidManifest `android:backupAgent` and a class implementing the `BackupAgent` interface with `onBackup` and `onRestore` methods.

Answer (score 3):

When you remove the app, all application data will be removed (external,internal,shared pref.) IF you use the the external storage related to your app.

For example the path to external storage would be:

(API 8+): getExternalFilesDir()

(API 7-): getExternalStorageDirectory()

If you want to persist data you might want to write in a shareable external

(API 8+): getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()

(API 7-): getExternalStorageDirectory()

**Music/** - Media scanner classifies all media found here as user music.

**Podcasts/** - Media scanner classifies all media found here as a podcast.

**Ringtones/** - Media scanner classifies all media found here as a ringtone.

**Alarms/** - Media scanner classifies all media found here as an alarm sound.

**Notifications/** - Media scanner classifies all media found here as a notification sound.

**Pictures/** - All photos (excluding those taken with the camera).

**Movies/** - All movies (excluding those taken with the camcorder).

**Download/** - Miscellaneous downloads.

Explained in [Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)

As i remember, the shared path doesn't get erased after your app uninstall, but the bad thing is that other apps can have access to it.

BTW, external is just an example, you might want to use internal storage since not all phones will have sd cards.

Answer (score 0):

Save your data to SD card, to prevend data removal on uninstall. Or store it on remote server.

Comment: what about making something on a settings tab where the user can save the data and load from a file?

Comment: It's irrelevant how you do that. It's important to save it in right place. and SD card or remote server is the one.